# Why would my background disappear when adding a button?

Tags: android

Why would the code below fail?

I have a blue relativeLayout in my main.xml.  On click I'm adding a green button.

When running on my Motorola Xoom I click the screen and I see the green button show up, but the background changes from blue to black.  If I click again my blue background shows.  Click again and I see black...

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

```
package com.android.mikeviewtester;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ViewTesterActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

        // set the relative layout as our view  
        setContentView( R.layout.main );

        RelativeLayout currentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.MyRelativeLayout );

        // set a listener  
        currentView.setOnTouchListener( (android.view.View.OnTouchListener) mOnTouchListener );
    }

    private android.view.View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener = new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if ( v != null )
                v.onTouchEvent( event );

            if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {

                android.widget.RelativeLayout vw = (android.widget.RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.MyRelativeLayout );

                // create and add a new cyan button 
                Button btn = new Button( ViewTesterActivity.this );
                btn.setBackgroundColor( Color.GREEN );
                vw.addView( btn, 100, 100 );
                vw.invalidate();
                btn.invalidate();
            }

            return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MyRelativeLayout"
    android:background="#0000FF">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Might have something to do with the viewgroup.layoutparams you set for the new button, I'm not sure, would have to fiddle around with it ;) tryed invalidate after you add aswell?

Comment: I played around with the layoutparams settings with no luck.  Tried using addView( btn, 100, 100 ) to avoid layoutparams alltogether.  I've tried invalidate() and invalidateRect(..).  When I call getDrawingRect() on the view I get the entire canvas rect so that seems okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from calling setContentView() method at the en of onCreate(). 
try like that

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    // set the relative layout as our view 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    currentView  = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);

    // create a red button 
    Button btn = new Button( this );
    btn.setBackgroundColor( Color.RED );
    Relative.LayoutParams params = new Relative.LayoutParams( 100, 100 );
    currentView.addView( btn, params );

    // setup the view (blue background) 
    currentView.setBackgroundColor( Color.BLUE );
    currentView.setOnTouchListener( (android.view.View.OnTouchListener) mOnTouchListener );
}
```

And your main.xml file should be like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/main"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was hoping that would do the trick.  But I still see the issue.  I updated the code above to show what I currently have.

Comment: I just really simplified the code, setting the bg color in the xml and I don't add a button in onCreate().  Starting to wonder if adding it in the listener is the issue.  Not sure why though.

Comment: Ok so try vw.postInvalidate(); in place of vw.invalidate(); and remove btn.invalidate() in your onTouch() method.

Comment: There you go!  Thanks so much.  Where's the Send Money button?  My only hesitation is that it introduces a some flicker, which I can live with.  I just don't understand why the post of the invalidation is required in this case, seems like an invalidate() would do the trick.

Comment: no because you should use invalidate() only when you are on the UI-thread. For more info check the doc: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate().

Comment: I was under the impression that the listener runs in the UI thread.  Do you know if that's not the case?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether the error is coming from that but you are not using correctly layout params.
The layout params that you should use for a view are the params coming from the parent.
In your case, you should use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams for your buttons and I suppose a FrameLAyout.LayoutParams for your relative layout.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know even if its not causing this problem.  I updated the code (still breaks) above.